# How to retrieve Data Export info from api without screen scraping?

Tags: api, data-export

How to get the data export information (links), once the weekly full data export is complete, through api? is it stored in any object? can we fetch that information without doing a screen scraping?

Is there any other way other than the answer mentioned in the following post :-

[Automate the downloading of Data Export zip files](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/295/automate-the-downloading-of-data-export-zip-files)

Comment: I haven't seen anything other than screen scrapping or using a download manager from a browser extension. Maybe vote for some ideas to automate the process - [Weekly Data Export - Ability to automate file transfer via web service](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000KmX4AAK)